# How to make my IP address appear to have a specific prefix (when connecting to a ssh server)?

Tags: networking, ssh, ip

I have ssh access to several machines at our university computing center, but they only allow connections from within university network which means I have to go on campus everytime I need to run a simulation, collect results, etc.

Is there any way to make my IP address have a specific prefix so that ident protocol on that machine allow me access? I don't expect a specific or complete answer just give me hints where should I look.

Comment: Unless your university has a VPN you can connect to what you want is not possible.  If a VPN is offered then your problem is already solved.

Comment: Grab a LART and go beat your idiot admins with it.  There's no reason ssh shouldn't be allowed from outside.

Comment: It offers a vpn but it's on-campus only as well.

Comment: ...what is the point of a campus-only VPN?

Comment: See if the university has a [jump host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_Server) that you can use. This is a server that you _are_ allowed to SSH into from outside. From the jump host you'd be able to connect to the hosts which you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

There is. Get on the universities network. Usually you do that by physically going there.

An alternative is via a VPN. You can ask campus IT if they allow that.
(Basically that will behave the same as if you run a very long network cable from your home to the university).

Comment: Obviously I know that I have access on campus. It offers a vpn but it's on campus only as well.